# it doesn't save any thing in the csv file?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, scrapy

i'm trying to **scrape** some data from a website but it doesn't save any thing in the csv file

```
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse) 
        
def parse(self, response):
    name = shoes.css('a.store-name::text').extract()
    review_count = shoes.css('a.rating-info rtl-mode::text').extract()
    price = shoes.css('span.price-current::text').extract()
    image_link = shoes.css('.place-container img::attr(src)').extract()

    with open('urls.csv', 'w') as f:
        for u in name| review_count| price| image_link:
            f.write(u + "\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

As Win Hermanans mentioned you definitely should use the [feed Exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html).

It will be as simple as

```
def parse(self, response):
    name = shoes.css('a.store-name::text').extract()
    review_count = shoes.css('a.rating-info rtl-mode::text').extract()
    price = shoes.css('span.price-current::text').extract()
    image_link = shoes.css('.place-container img::attr(src)').extract()

    for i in range(len(name)):# we are looping beause extract() will give you a list and we want to get all the elements in seperate rows.
        yield{'name':name[i],
              'review_count':review_count[i],
              'price':price[i],
              'image_link':image_link[i],
           }
```

And you can simply pass **-o myData.csv** while running the crawler.

`scrapy crawl mycrawler -o myData.csv`

you can even get json and xml.

`scrapy crawl mycrawler -o myData.json`

`scrapy crawl mycrawler -o myData.xml`

Now you should see a **myData.csv** with all your data in your project folder.

However in about why the data is not being populated in your csv file above. its because you are overwriting each column. While creating the `urls.csv` file you are opening it as write. So everything will be overwritten. You can try with append parameter.

```
def parse(self, response):
    name = shoes.css('a.store-name::text').extract()
    review_count = shoes.css('a.rating-info rtl-mode::text').extract()
    price = shoes.css('span.price-current::text').extract()
    image_link = shoes.css('.place-container img::attr(src)').extract()

    for i in range(len(name)):# we are looping beause extract() will give you a list and we want to get all the elements in seperate rows.
    with open(filename,'a',newline='') as csvf:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(csvf)
        csv_writer.writerow([name[i],review_count[i],price[i],image_link[i]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the results to a file in the parse, try using the following approach:
- Create an item (in items.py):

```
import scrapy
class ShoeItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = Field()
    review_count = Field()
    price = Field()
    image_link = Field()
```

- Yield the item in parse:

```
from ..items import ShoeItem
def parse(self, response):
    name = shoes.css('a.store-name::text').extract()
    review_count = shoes.css('a.rating-info rtl-mode::text').extract()
    price = shoes.css('span.price-current::text').extract()
    image_link = shoes.css('.place-container img::attr(src)').extract()
    item = ShoeItem()
    item['name'] = name
    item['review_count'] = review_count
    item['price'] = price
    item['image_link'] = image_link
    yield item
```

- Launch the spider as follows to put the results in a csv file:

```
scrapy crawl (spidername) -o urls.csv
```

- Alternatively you can create a pipeline that write to the csv files, similar to the example here in the [docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file)